# Can not add .json file in Oracle SQL Developer to create new connection

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can not add .json file in Oracle SQL Developer to create new connection. I clicked import connection from Connections, then in click on browse button to add files. But .json files are not listing and there only two file types in file type drop down, properties and xml. How to import .json file ?

Comment: Did you export from a recent version, and are importing into an old version? Which version of SQL Developer are you using, and are you able to upgrade to the current version?

Comment: I am using SQL Developer 17.4.1.

Comment: 17.4.1 had xml based connection files...go download 21.4.1 and you'll be good

Comment: I could upload .json file after upgrading to 19.0.1. Thanks